# coffeescript refactoring

Tags: coffeescript

Is there any coffeescript specific trickery that would make this look neater:

```
index = (->
          if segment == 'index'
            return 0
          else if segment == 'inbox'
            return 2

          1
        )()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a `switch` expression:

```
index = switch segment
  when 'index' then 0
  when 'inbox' then 2
  else 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inline `if ... then ... else` statement broken up into multiple lines (for readability) by using the `\` character.

```
index = if segment == 'index' then 0 \
        else if segment == 'inbox' then 2 \
        else 1
```

This is useful if your conditional logic is too complex for a simple `switch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the CoffeeScript-specific existential operator:

```
index = {'index': 0, 'inbox': 2}[segment] ? 1
```

You could also use an inline if statement to get rid of the function call:

```
index = if segment == 'index' then 0 else if segment == 'inbox' then 2 else 1
```

But an inline if wouldn't be any harder in straight Javascript:

```
index = segment == 'index' ? 0 : segment == 'inbox' ? 2 : 1
```